# Error while updating a project

Tags: eclipse

I get the following error when trying to "update" my eclipse project :

```
failed due to an internal error (took 0:00.337)
   Error: Problem writing resource 
   '/sspaceex/src/PLWL_implementations/CVS/Template'. 
   A resource already exists on disk 
   '/home/ray/workspace2/sspaceex/src/PLWL_implementations/CVS/Template'.
   Error: A resource already exists on disk 
   '/home/ray/workspace2/sspaceex/src/PLWL_implementations/CVS/Template'.
   ***
```

Any idea why this error and how to get rid of this?

Comment: delete the resource and try to do an update

Answer (score 2):

```
Error: Problem writing resource 
'/sspaceex/src/PLWL_implementations/CVS/Template'.  
A resource already exists on disk 
'/home/ray/workspace2/sspaceex/src/PLWL_implementations/CVS/Template'
```

Try to close as many active process as possible to check if another application does not "block" that resource.
As [Narayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81367/narayan) suggests in the comments, if it exists, check if you can delete it manually (outside eclipse) before attempting another refresh in eclipse.

> The server reported an error while performing the "`cvs update`" command:

```
sspaceex: cvs update: nothing known about `doxygen/htmlclasscontinuous__sets_1_1sequence__transform__coll__graph.md5'
```

That should mean that the resource is removed from the file system, but not removed from CVS (i.e. on CVS server, an entry exists for this resource).
That is consistent with the failed update which was unable to write in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Doh,

I had to updated project configuration. This created the folder that Eclipse didn't like. Then close the project. Then reopen it. Then update project configuration again. Do a little dance and song, and violla!

In that order.

Cheers,
M

Answer (score 2):

I hit this issue due to resource wildcard exclusions in my project. My project and CVS repository contains numerous file types that I never edit (for example, *.asm assembly files). To reduce workspace view clutter and to make searches faster, I had excluded these file types from my project when I had originally created it.

From what I can tell, this causes Eclipse/CVS to think it needs to add all these "missing" files to my project when I attempt to do an update (as evident in the incoming changes in the Team Synchronizing view). When I removed the resource filter from my project, the update process was able to complete.

This is sort of a pain because I have to choose between the two, or I have to keep adding and removing these filters based on when I want to perform an update.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is confused because a file exists that shouldn't be there. Close the project and synchronize again and it should go away.

[EDIT] `cvs update: nothing known about '...'` means that Eclipse believes that this file is under CVS control and the CVS server says "I have no idea what you're talking about".

Reasons can be that your CVS server got corrupted, somehow, of that the contents of the files `CVS/Entries` and `CVS/Entries.Extra` is wrong (Eclipse records what is under CVS control in these files).

I suggest that you delete the project in Eclipse (**don't** check "Also delete files on disk"), then rename the project on disk to something else, and do a clean checkout.

After the checkout, you can copy any changes you make back (but **don't** copy the CVS directories or anything inside of them!)

Comment: no i didn't update the project from outside eclipse. Closing the project and then trying to synchronize resulted in yet another error: 

Problems reported while synchronizing CVS Workspace. 0 of 1 resources were synchronized.
  An error occurred synchronizing /sspaceex: The server reported an error while performing the "cvs update" command.
    The server reported an error while performing the "cvs update" command.
      sspaceex: cvs update: nothing known about `doxygen/html/classcontinuous__sets_1_1sequence__transform__coll__graph.md5'

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. For me, it had to do with the fact that eclipse was out of sync with the file system. I just had to refresh the project (select the project, then hit F5) and the "update" was okay.

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually delete the resource, then refresh the project, then update, and it worked.

Note: I have *Build Automatically* turned off, it might be that the refresh will cause an automatic rebuild that will create the resource again, so make sure there is no build done between deleting, refreshing, and updating.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to use "Project->clean" after turning automatic builds off.